# locus of complex number 2

Tags: complex-numbers

**Que:**

> If $\arg\left(\dfrac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)=\pi$ then what is the locus of $z$?.

**Doubt**

In my textbook it is written that it represents the straight line joining $A(Z_1)$ and $B(Z_2)$ but excluding the segment $AB$.
[image]

Is it right or wrong?

**But According to me** the locus of $z$ is the straight line joining the line segment $A(Z_1)$ and  $B(Z_2)$
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right.
$$\arg \frac xy = \arg x - \arg y + 2\pi n$$
so
$$\arg\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}=\pi$$ 
means the vector $z-z_1$ is parallel to, but points in opposite direction than $z-z_2$.
This implies $z$ is *between* $z_1$ and $z_2$, hence the answer: 'an interior of the line segment $\overline {z_1 z_2}$'.